# How to deploying a contract address on the front-end?

Tags: web3js, javascript

So I'm using web3@0.26.0 to deploy my contract so I can get my contract address from it. And I used it from my backend too and it works. But when I want to implement it on my frontend, I've got an error which says

> (Uncaught TypeError: t.filter is not a function) for this line "let deployContractAddress = MyContract.new({ ... "

via my console on Chrome and also my metamask won't popup to signed the contract deploy. Here is my code :

```
function deployContract() {
        var r = confirm('Are you sure to deploy this contract?');
        if (r == true) {
            var contractABI = document.getElementById('abi').value;
            var contractBytecode = document.getElementById('bytecode').value;
            let web3 = new Web3();
            web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(window.web3.currentProvider));

        //define default account[0]
        const address = web3.eth.getAccounts[0];

        let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(
            contractABI
        );

        let deployContractAddress = MyContract.new({
            from: address,
            data: '0x' + contractBytecode,
            gas: '4700000'
        }, function (e, contract) {
            // console.log(e, contract);
            if (!e) {
                console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address +
                    ' with transactionHash: ' + contract
                    .transactionHash);
                global.newContractAddress = contract.address;
                global.newContractTxHash = contract.transactionHash;
                console.log(
                    'SUCCESS!');
            } else {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });

    } else {
        alert('Contract deploy action has been canceled!');
        return false;
    };
};
```

So please help me, thank you~ :)

Comment: By the least, you should specify which line of code throws this error (since there is no `filter` in your code)!!!

Comment: Oh i'm sorry but this error refers to this line "let deployContractAddress = MyContract.new({ ... "

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you should use `deploy` instead of `new` (at least that's the case on web3.js v1.x).